# parse a HTML file with table using Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I got problem with my python parser. its a part of my file:

```
<tr>
    <td class="zeit"><div>03.12. 10:45:00</div></td>
    <td class="system"><div><a target="_blank" href="detail.php?host=CG&factor=2&delay=1&Y=15">CG</div></a></td>
    <td class="fehlertext"><div>System steht nicht zur Verfügung!</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="zeit"><div>03.12. 10:10:01</div></td>
    <td class="system"><div><a target="_blank" href="detail.php?host=DEXProd&factor=2&delay=5&Y=15">DEX</div></a></td>
    <td class="fehlertext"><div>ssh: Connection refused Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="zeit"><div>03.12. 06:23:06</div></td>
    <td class="system"><div><a target="_blank" href="detail.php?host=FRAUD&factor=2&delay=1&Y=15">Boni</div></a></td>
    <td class="fehlertext"><div>ID Fehler</div></td>
</tr>
```

Now i'm going to get few information for each:

1) DATA 2) NAME 3) ERROR

so for 1st table should be:

03.12. 10:45:00 CG System steht nicht zur Verfügung!

i was reading some information about BS4 but i have no idea how to initiate below python script.

-bash-3.2$ cat out2.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open ("file.txt", "r") as myfile:
    html=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tag = soup.findAll('a') #all "a" tag in a list

count = 0
passx = 0
for i in tag:
        if count > 3:
                print "-------------------------------"
                #FILE.write("-------------------------------" + "\n")
                count = 0
                passx = 0
        if passx == 0:
                print i['href']
                #FILE.write(i['href'] + "\n")
                passx = 1
        print i.text
        count = count + 1

#FILE.close()
```

Comment: _"i have no idea how to initiate below python script."_. Are you asking how to run Python programs? You can execute a script by doing `python out2.py` from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Find all](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) `tr` tags and get `td` tags [by `class` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class):

```
# encoding: utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = u"""
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="zeit"><div>03.12. 10:45:00</div></td>
        <td class="system"><div><a target="_blank" href="detail.php?host=CG&factor=2&delay=1&Y=15">CG</div></a></td>
        <td class="fehlertext"><div>System steht nicht zur Verfügung!</div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="zeit"><div>03.12. 10:10:01</div></td>
        <td class="system"><div><a target="_blank" href="detail.php?host=DEXProd&factor=2&delay=5&Y=15">DEX</div></a></td>
        <td class="fehlertext"><div>ssh: Connection refused Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer</div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="zeit"><div>03.12. 06:23:06</div></td>
        <td class="system"><div><a target="_blank" href="detail.php?host=FRAUD&factor=2&delay=1&Y=15">Boni</div></a></td>
        <td class="fehlertext"><div>ID Fehler</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    zeit = tr.find('td', class_='zeit').get_text(strip=True)
    system = tr.find('td', class_='system').get_text(strip=True)
    fehlertext = tr.find('td', class_='fehlertext').get_text(strip=True)

    print zeit, system, fehlertext
```

Prints:

```
03.12. 10:45:00 CG System steht nicht zur Verfügung!
03.12. 10:10:01 DEX ssh: Connection refused Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
03.12. 06:23:06 Boni ID Fehler
```

Comment: cool! but is it possible to get into data string txt from file? i got error with f = open('sth.txt', 'w') html = f

Comment: @MiK `BeautifulSoup(open("file.txt"))` should do it.