# How to get data from nested HTML using BeautifulSoup in Django

Tags: python, html, django, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn web scraping and I'm stuck at a point where the data I want is wrapped by a div tag as so:

```
<div class="maincounter-number">
<span style="color:#aaa">803 </span>
</div>
```

There are several data like that and I need all (eg. 803). So i guess I need to do `soup.find_all(...)` but I don't know what to put inside. Anyone help?

I am working in python (Django.)

Comment: `for item in soup.findAll("span", style="color:#aaa"): print(item.text)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parse a HTML file with table using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272247/parse-a-html-file-with-table-using-python)

Comment: Not exactly, since in my case, the container iteself repeats (div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are looking to do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '<div class="maincounter-number"><span style="color:#aaa">803 </span></div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('span', {'style': 'color:#aaa'})[0].get_text())
```

If you just want to query the text in the div and search by class:

```
print(soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'maincounter-number'})[0].get_text())
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd method and it worked. But I get the data for the 1st object only. The container (div element) is what repeats for 4 times and I need all 4 of the data. When I do  'print(soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'maincounter-number'})[:4].get_text())' it shows 'ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?' error

Comment: as per αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη comment you need to store and iterate the object and you can perform nested find's per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510966/beautiful-soup-nested-tag-search